# Visual Studio 2022 can't compile code that CompilerExplorer does using the same compiler

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++20, visual-studio-2022

I'm building a STL-friendly `Allocator<T>` to track allocations based on a `Tag`

`Allocator<T>` expects `T` to have a `static constexpr` identifier 'tag'

At some point on template deduction/instantiation, `T` is replaced by `std::_Container_proxy` which has no 'tag' identifier

I don't understand why CompilerExplorer works using the same compiler than VS2022 but the second fails

- CompilerExplorer compiler: x64 msvc 19.33
- VS2022 `_MSC_VER`: 1933
- C++ version: 20

GCC 10> also compiles fine

This is the code:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

namespace Memory {
    enum class Tag {
        None = 0,
        User = 1,
    };

    void* allocate(const std::size_t size, const Tag tag) {
        std::cout << "Allocate " << size << " bytes (tag: " << (int) tag << ")\n";
        return ::operator new(size);
    }

    void deallocate(void* block, const std::size_t size, const Tag tag) {
        std::cout << "Deallocate " << size << " bytes (tag: " << (int) tag << ")\n";
        ::operator delete(block, size);
    }

    template <typename T>
    class Allocator {
    public:
        using value_type = T;

        Allocator() = default;

        template <typename U>
        Allocator(const Allocator<U>&) noexcept {}

        template <typename U>
        bool operator==(const Allocator<U>&) const noexcept { return true; }

        template <typename U>
        bool operator!=(const Allocator<U>&) const noexcept { return false; }

        T* allocate(const std::size_t count) const {
            return (T*) Memory::allocate(sizeof(T) * count, T::tag);
        }

        void deallocate(void* ptr, const std::size_t count) const noexcept {
            Memory::deallocate(ptr, sizeof(T) * count, T::tag);
        }
    };
}

struct NoneTest {
    static constexpr auto tag { Memory::Tag::None };
};

struct UserTest {
    static constexpr auto tag { Memory::Tag::User };
};

int main() {
    std::vector<NoneTest, Memory::Allocator<NoneTest>> noneVector;
    std::vector<UserTest, Memory::Allocator<UserTest>> userVector;
    noneVector.reserve(42);
    userVector.reserve(73);
    return 0;
}
```

This is the expected output:

```
Allocate 42 bytes (tag: 0)
Allocate 73 bytes (tag: 1)
Deallocate 73 bytes (tag: 1)
Deallocate 42 bytes (tag: 0)
```

This is the error:

```
1>C:\dev\test\test\main.cpp(37,63): error C2039: 'tag': is not a member of 'std::_Container_proxy'
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\include\xmemory(1044,8): message : see declaration of 'std::_Container_proxy'
1>C:\dev\test\test\main.cpp(36,1): message : while compiling class template member function 'T *Memory::Allocator<T>::allocate(const size_t) const'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=std::_Container_proxy
1>        ]
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\include\xmemory(1064,44): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'T *Memory::Allocator<T>::allocate(const size_t) const' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=std::_Container_proxy
1>        ]
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\include\vector(832): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'Memory::Allocator<_Newfirst>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Newfirst=std::_Container_proxy
1>        ]
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\include\vector(829,1): message : while compiling class template member function 'std::vector<UserTest,Memory::Allocator<UserTest>>::~vector(void) noexcept'
1>C:\dev\test\test\main.cpp(56,56): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::vector<UserTest,Memory::Allocator<UserTest>>::~vector(void) noexcept' being compiled
1>C:\dev\test\test\main.cpp(56,56): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::vector<UserTest,Memory::Allocator<UserTest>>' being compiled
1>C:\dev\test\test\main.cpp(37,1): error C2065: 'tag': undeclared identifier
```

Comment: It might not be related. Are the compiler options the same on your vs2022 and CompilerExplorer? Please provide the live link of CompilerExplorer that compiles and the options of vs2022 in text.

Comment: Your allocator doesn't satisfy the requirements. In particular, an allocator can be rebound to an arbitrary type, and should be able to allocate memory for instances of that type; see [`allocator_traits::rebind_alloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits). The specific cause of the error is that you are building a debug build with iterator debugging enabled. In this build, MSVC STL implementation maintains additional data structures for debugging purposes, and uses the container's allocator for them. This tends to weed out nonconforming allocators.